# how to add activity indicator when address book name is selected in my application?

Tags: iphone, addressbook

i have a task to develop application with address book.

i have to develop the app to select name,photo,email,hompage,address from address book.when i select the record it take long time to add record.i want to add activity indicator when user select the record in address book table.

Please provide me some source for it.and help me please as fast as possible.

Comment: what is it that is taking long time? is it interacting with file system or external web service?

Comment: yes it is saving image to webservice at my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

`[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self.activityIndicator];`

and then

`[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];`

where activityIndicator is declared in .h file like -

`@property(nonatomic,retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;`

and synthesized in .m file -

`@synthesize activityIndicator;`

Answer (score 0):

This will do
   // declare and synthesize the object
    UIActivityIndicatorView         *activityIndicator; 
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

```
// on event function write this code
```

[activityIndicator startAnimating];

Comment: Ihave already given this but it is working in my view not on the address book table when user select contact. i want to display on address book table view which is opening in my application.